# Text field with both a placeholder/hint AND focus - possible?

Tags: jquery, forms, placeholder, autofocus

We have a survey where certain pages have a single textarea question. Since it's the only input, we want to have it focus on that box onload. But we also want to have a placeholder-style text in that same textarea.

There are quite a few solutions to making both functions work on all browsers such as [this one by Ajaxblender](http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-add-hints-form-auto-focus-using-javascript.html). But I want the *hint to remain after focus, then disappear when text is entered*. Any ideas?

Note - I realize the HTML specs state that the placeholder element should going away on focus. So maybe I should say that I want a "watermark". This UI is for older men with low computer literacy - they need any assistance we can provide them.

Must work with IE8 :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question, you could try something like

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="first">Instructions go here</textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#first').focus().one('keydown', function(){
    $(this).val('');    
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/AYRyH/

**Explanation**

1. An empty `.focus()` puts the focus on the field at onload.
2. `.one()` fires an event once for the element
3. On `keydown` we remove the current value, which are the instructions we added at the beginning.

### EDIT

Given your comment

> I need it to function a little more like a standard placeholder
>   though, so if you enter something, then delete it so the field is
>   blank, it goes back to displaying the original hint.

You could do this... capture the `value` and then place it back in the `textarea` on `blur` if there is nothing there.

```
var a = $('#first').val();

$('#first').focus().one('keydown', function(){
    $(this).val('');    
});

$('#first').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
       $(this).val(a); 
    }
})
```

**Example 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/AYRyH/1/

Comment: thanks that's exactly the direction I want to go. I need it to function a little more like a standard placeholder though, so if you enter something, then delete it so the field is blank, it goes back to displaying the original hint.